# Twig merge multiple things in an array

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

I'm trying to create an array with dates in it for an order system. Those dates corresponds with days that the shop can't deliver.

I'm having trouble to create that array since values are strings and that keeps getting producing an error with the `merge` filter. 
**I have only access to the frontend of the shop so I can't create custom functions whatsover.**

The end result need to be an array with all dates in it so I can use that as javascript array, like so:

```
var closed = [
  {{ closedDates }} // ["01-01-2018", "02-01-2018", etc...]      
];
```

So what I have is this:

1) Webshop fills in the single days they are closed and perhaps a range of days.
   That are three variables like:

```
 {{ closedDays }} {# produces eg 01-01-2018, 02-01-2018, 03-01-2018 { it's dd-mm-yy #} 
 {{ date_range_start }} {# produces eg. 10-01-2018 #}
 {{ date_range_end }} {# produces eg. 20-01-2018 #}
```

2) So what I did is this:

```
 {% set closedDates = [] %}    


  {% if theme.closedDays %}
    {% set foo = theme.closedDays %}
    {% for i in foo | slice(0, 5) %}
       {% set closedDates = closedDates | merge(i) %}
    {% endfor %}

  {% endif %}

  {% if theme.date_range_start and theme.date_range_end  %}
     {% set start_date = theme.date_range_start  %}
     {% set end_date = theme.date_range_end %}

     {# below function lists all days between start and end date #}
     {% for weekRange in range(start_date|date('U'), end_date|date('U'), 86400 ) %}
        {% set closedDates = closedDates | merge(weekRange | date('d-m-Y')) %} 
     {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

When I do it like above I get an error saying `The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes;`. But how do you create an array then with those values? That's only done with `merge` right?!

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Twig you can't just push elements to an array. Instead, you have to merge array with another array.

Given one array:

```
{% set firstArray = ['a', 'b'] %}
```

if you want to add element 'c', you have to merge it providing an array, even if you want to add single string element.

```
{% set firstArray = firstArray | merge(['c']) %}
```

---

If you work with associative arrays, it's analogical:

```
{% set secondArray = {'a': 'string a', 'b': 'string b' } %}
{% set secondArray = secondArray | merge({'b': 'overwritten!', 'c': 'string c' }) %}
```

The only diference is that element `b` will be overwritten with the value from the `secondArray`, so you'll get:

```
{
   'a': 'string a',
   'b': 'overwritten!',
   'c': 'string c'
}
```

Comment: Ok that's something I understand. However isn't that what I tried? Can you perhaps give an exam-ple based on my code?

Comment: Well @Meules, doesn't my answer contain some examples? I gave you an answer (with examples) which is likely to solve your error. You just want me to implement it for you in a scatter of your code, don't you? :)

Comment: Well not exactly :) I don't understand why my code does not work. I do the same like you. Only thing is that `closedDays`  array is empty by default. But you mean I should create an array for `weekRange` and `i` and then merge that with `closedDays`?

Comment: @Meules I'd really love to help you but have troubles understanding your issue. Naming in your pieces of code is not consistent. In your previous comment you refer to `closedDays`. Which one?
 **Try** **this:** `{% set closedDates = closedDates | merge([weekRange | date('d-m-Y')]) %}` _PS:_ _groetjes_ _uit_ _Breda_ _:)_

Comment: Well more or less.... Anyway your example made me clear that I forgot all brackets in the merge filter :( Secondly it helped a lot so I will accept it as answer!

Comment: @Meules cool! Happy to hear! And curious as well... so what was the issue (besides brackets) after all?

Comment: What about using `+`  instead of `merge`?

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu `+` is a Math operator in twig. I believe you can not use it to merge arrays.

Comment: I have used `+` to join/merge like `list` in `python` and `array` in `PHP`. But for it's usage you need to find out where will it fail.

Comment: Or you can just read documentation? At least before giving hints ;-)

Comment: + operator will join dictionary like or associative array in twig. It's behavior for array is not favourable as of now.